# Cyclic Groups/Group Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If g and h have orders 15 and 16 respectively in a group G, what is the order of ⟨g⟩ ∩ ⟨h⟩? Does the product gh belong to this intersection since g and h are both elements of a group and thus gh ∈ G under closure, if not, why?

Comment: Please use proper math notation to ask a question. It's hard for people to understand your question if you don't write clearly

Comment: While $gh\in G$, this does not show the product belongs to *both* subgroups $\langle g \rangle$ and $\langle h \rangle$.

Comment: Sorry, those are meant to be cyclic subgroups generated by g and h...

Comment: Understood, but you should think about what sort of element belongs to both subgroups.

Comment: The identity does, but could be that it is the only one element belonging to both subgroups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\langle g\rangle\cap\langle h\rangle=e$ by Lagrange.

In general, there is no guarantee that $gh\in \langle g\rangle\cap\langle h\rangle$.

For instance, in this case it would imply $g=h^{-1}$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you a million times.

Answer (score 1):

Since a $\langle g \rangle$ is a cyclic group of order 15, by the fundamental theorem of cyclic groups, any element in it has order $1,3,5$ or $15$. Similarly $\langle h \rangle$ has only elements of order $1,2,4,8$ or $16$.  Hence $\langle g \rangle \cap \langle h \rangle$ is the trivial group. An example of the empty group would be $g=(1,0)$ and $h=(0,1)$ in the group $\mathbb{Z}_{15} \times \mathbb{Z}_{16}$. Clearly $gh$ does can't be in the intersection.

Comment: Wow! Thank you lot.